# Question about uncorrected errors

Tags: discussion, editing

I have noticed on this forum that answers are accepted, irrespective of minor errors. I am saying this because I have seen some of the answers with wrong capitalization and others with minor grammar issues like proper punctuations go unnoticed.

I am wondering, why senior users who help students like me don’t correct everything that is written on this forum?

Answer (score 13):

Some time ago, ELL as a community decided that sometimes it's best to leave some minor mistakes in **questions**, because those mistakes might help other users more accurately gauge the experience level of the learner asking the question. So that's one reason we don't correct "everything" written in ELL.

**Answers**, though, are another matter – particularly accepted answers. In that case, I agree that minor errors ought to be corrected. As to why they aren't, I'm guessing that it's simply because those who spot the errors are not correcting them.

No Stack Exchange has a senior editor who reviews all answers, or all accepted answers. It's up to the community to fix these up as we find them, so it's no surprise that some go uncorrected.

As a footnote, I won't chastise anyone who leaves such errors alone. Everyone has their own reasons for participating. Some like to read answers, others like to leave answers. Some like to improve tags, some like to improve titles, some like to correct minor mistakes. Some like to leave flags and some like to leave things alone. It's all good. This diversity is what makes us a community and it's what makes the community work.

If a few folks suddenly felt like it was their duty and obligation to proofread and correct every accepted answer, they might well burn out, and we could end up losing some very valuable members of our community. Fix 'em as you find 'em, but if fixing them is not your thing, that's okay, too.

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to remember that this site has many native English speakers who are happy to help answer questions but it is also populated with users who are English *learners*. Everyone is welcome to post answers regardless of knowledge level or native speaker status and, as such, those users are likely to make a few errors in their attempt to answer questions.

That is not to say that native speakers don't make mistakes, too. We do it all the time!

We (the users of this site) do the best we can to fix what we can fix but there's only so much we can do without everyone's help.

If you see a problem in an answer - fix it. If you have sufficient reputation, edit. If you don't, suggest an edit if you can meet the character requirement or, if you can't meet it, consider posting a comment on the answer to note what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons.  The first is, I'm lazy.

That accounts for most of it.  But the second reason is that, I can't edit an answer unless I change more than a certain number of characters.  This prevents me from correcting single spelling or punctuation mistakes, much as I might want to.

For the record, I appreciate when others fix my own minor spelling and grammar mistakes, which are not infrequent.  I usually answer questions while doing other things, and mistakes are inevitable.

Comment: At 19.1K reputation, you could edit and change only a single character in a post. It's just the folks that must have their edits peer-reviewed that have a character limit (most likely to prevent review queues from being stuffed with trivial edits).

Comment: @ColleenV  Well dang.  Now I guess I have to fall back on my first excuse  :)

Comment: I'm assuming that's because you're too lazy to make up a new one ? :P (and that's absolutely intended as a joke, but I've had a long day at work and I'm thinking now maybe it came across a little rough)

Comment: @ColleenV I really should just make a nice long stack of excuses so I can pop off the top one when I need a new one .  (And no worries, I'm not that delicate  ;)